# NumPy and Python 3 - Error message on import

Tags: python, numpy

Importing NumPy in Python 3, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import numpy
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py:91: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility
  from .mtrand import *
>>>
```

However, `numpy` is imported after that (e.g. I can call `dir(numpy)` to list its contents)

a) What does this message mean?

b) Since I am new to NumPy: Can you suggest a test for me to make sure NumPy is functioning properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this bug report](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2103) which seems to say that the warning is not important.  It looks like the bug report was marked as fixed, so future version of NumPy will not display the warning.

Answer (score 1):

According to this bug report, it's a non-issue: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2103

And the warning has been fixed in git.